# HTML/CSS/Javascript - Align Text In Table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, alignment

I am trying to align the text in my table. It currently looks like this:

[image]

I would like to align the tile (in bold) in the center. Also, I am trying to get the values on the right, moved to the left.

Currently I have:

Javascript:

```
var table = $('<table/>',
    {
        id: 'table',
        "class":'tables'

    });

// ************************ Row 1 ************************************
row1 = $('<tr></tr>');
var head = $('<th></th>').addClass('dealHead').text(value.dealTitle);
row1.append(head);
table.append(row1);
// ********************************************************************

// ************************ Row 2 ************************************
row2 = $('<tr></tr>');
var col1 = $('<td></td>').addClass('name').text("Name: ");
var col2 = $('<td></td>').addClass('nameValue').text(value.name);

row2.append(col1);
row2.append(col2);                  
table.append(row2);
// ********************************************************************

// ************************ Row 3 ************************************
row3 = $('<tr></tr>');
col1 = $('<td></td>').addClass('address').text("Address: ");
col2 = $('<td></td>').addClass('addressValue').text(value.address);

row3.append(col1);
row3.append(col2);                  
table.append(row3);

// ********************************************************************

table.appendTo('body')
```

CSS:

```
body
{
background-color:#5CD65C;
}

.dealHead
{
text-align:center;
}


.name
{
border-top:thick double #0F0F00;
border-left:thick double #0F0F00;
border-bottom:thick double #0F0F00;

}

.nameValue
{

border-top:thick double #0F0F00;
border-right:thick double #0F0F00;
border-bottom:thick double #0F0F00;
text-align:left;

}

.address
{
border-top:thick double #0F0F00;
border-left:thick double #0F0F00;
border-bottom:thick double #0F0F00;
}

.addressValue
{

border-top:thick double #0F0F00;
border-right:thick double #0F0F00;
border-bottom:thick double #0F0F00;
text-align:left;
}


.tables
{
width="400";
border-collapse: collapse;

}
```

HTML

Pretty much an empty `<body>`

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: in order to center the header you add colspan=2 that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## CSS

> `.tables { width="400"; ...`

should be

```
.tables { width: 400px; ...
```

In order to have both cells the same with:

```
.tables td { width: 50%; }
```

## Javascript

> `var head = $('<th></th>').addClass('dealHead').text(value.dealTitle);`

This is only one cell, make it like two:

```
var head = $('<th colspan="2"></th>').addClass('dealHead').text(value.dealTitle);
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/J6tQR/)

Comment: Thanks for that! Also made use of the `width` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In order to center the header you add colspan=2 that works,align the td's you have a class so add text-align-left like this

```
row1 = $('<tr></tr>');
var head = $('<th colspan="2"></th>').addClass('dealHead').text(value.dealTitle);
```

CSS

```
.test td {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Example HTML

```
<table class="test">
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Title</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the best way to do this, and can't think of another way.

Answer (score 0):

if this is plain html, I could have made the header `<th>` to be of `colspan=2`.
similarly make your header

```
var head = $('<th colspan="2"></th>').addClass('dealHead').text(value.dealTitle);
```

hope this would help.